# Apache Http Client 5.1.3 takes too long to execute a http request

Tags: spring, multithreading, spring-boot, http, apache-httpclient-5.x

I'm building an online payment platform API backend using spring boot. In the pay process, the backend will send a https request to a pay service like stripe (not stripe exactly in my case). I'm using Apache Http Client 5.1.3 to make the https request.

In my pom.xml, the dependency is as follows:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient5</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

The helper method that makes the https request is as follows:

```
    @Override
    public String makeHttpsRequest(String requestXMLString) throws IOException, ParseException {
        // request
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(PAY_GATEWAY_URL);
        StringEntity requestStringEntity = new StringEntity(requestXMLString, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        postRequest.setEntity(requestStringEntity);

        // response
        CloseableHttpResponse postResponse = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
        HttpEntity responseEntity = postResponse.getEntity();
        String responseXMLString = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);

        // close resources
        postResponse.close();
        httpClient.close();
        
        return responseXMLString;
    }
```

Sometimes the line `CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();` takes about 2 seconds to finish, and the line `CloseableHttpResponse postResponse = httpClient.execute(postRequest);` always takes about 3 seconds to finish, which in total gives the user really bad pay experience.

I'm wondering if there's any way that I can customize the http request to make it faster. By contrast, we had another system that was built on .NET and makes the same https request to the same service, the system always takes about 1 second to process the payment. These two systems run under the same network settings.

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can define following

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
```

at instance level and don't need to close it after each and every call. Apache Commons Http Clients are thread safe and will support multiple requests. This way you can reduce a lot of latency. Apart from that you can not do much in terms of performance improvement.